# How can retain the value of button which been clicked for submit if there are 2 submit button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

There are two 'Submit' button and one of the button using preventdefault to perform checking and then unbind the submit and submit through the default event. It cannot detect which button been submitted.

I am using the statement below but it only works if there is one submit button. It will return blank page if there are two buttons.

```
$('form').unbind('submit').submit();
```

function.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '.....', 'id' => 'form']) !!}

    e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'check/'+'{{$id}}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data!=""){
                            swal({
                                ........
                            },function (isConfirm) {
                                if(isConfirm){
                                    $('form').unbind('submit').submit();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: can't you give a value to the button?

Comment: I gave value to the button but it only works without the ajax checking, when i perform ajax checking and only allow default event then it dont get the value of the button on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Give each button its own name and it should work fine. Make sure the name is a legal name.

Comment: I gave value to the button but it only works without the ajax checking, when i perform ajax checking and only allow default event then it dont get the value of the button on server side.